# How do I print words in an array, and including the spaces between them?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, input, java.util.scanner

The following program only works for 1 word or a number. If my input is more than 1 word, then after the 'space', the output leaves out the rest of the input. So, i want the print statement in the for-loop to print out the whole input as a String type including the spaces. Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.*;

class characters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int upperC = 0;
        int lowerC = 0;
        //char ch;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input: ");
        String svar = input.next();

        String[] ary = svar.split("");

        for (int i=0; i< ary.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ary[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, you probably want to `split` using a space `" "` not the empty string `""`. Then, when you're printing, you want to ADD a space, so `System.out.println(ary[i] + " ");`

Comment: That doesn't work, I did that also.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the behavier as an example?

Comment: Try with StringTokenizer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: His problem is the `input.next();` it only reads the input till the first whitspace

Comment: Do `input.nextLine()` instead and it will work.

Comment: I'll be googling the usage of these for better understandings :) thank you all. I tried your StringTokenizer Andreas. It worked also :)

Comment: @user3144097 You should pick a best answer instead of changing the title. Even if the best answer is your own.

Comment: mawburn, i cant vote answers, that's why... and i didnt answer it myself, as i said in the answer.

Comment: @user3144097 There is a greyed out check mark under each downvote that you will see only on your questions after they have been open for 15minutes (or so). That's the "Best Answer" marker. It will turn into a green checkmark after you click it and you will get +2 points. It is separate from voting and it will mark your question resolved.

Comment: But the answer is in the comments.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

`String svar = input.next();`

with

`String svar = input.nextLine();`

Comment: You should expand your answer to explain why the original line didn't work, and how the new code behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

   class characters {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int upperC = 0;
    int lowerC = 0;
    //char ch;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter input: ");
    String word = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("your complete String"+word);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to kai, this is the right code that worked for me. thanks! :)

```
import java.util.*;

class characters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int upperC = 0;
        int lowerC = 0;
        char ch;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input: ");
        String svar = input.nextLine();

        String[] ary = svar.split(" ");

        for (int i=0; i< ary.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ary[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```